# display data from database to dropdown CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having difficulty with display data from the db to dropdown.

This is what I have tried:

**Model.php**

```
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function getAllGroups()
        {
            /*
            $query = $this->db->get('location');

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                echo $row->description;
            }*/

            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT description FROM location');

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
                echo $row->description;
            }

            //echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
        }
```

**Controller.php**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Delivery_controller extends CI_Controller{
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('delivery_model');

        }
        public function index()
        {

            $data['title']= 'Warehouse - Delivery';
            $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/navbar',$data);
            $this->load->view('delivery_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('include/sidebar',$data);
            $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
        $data['groups'] = $this->delivery_model->getAllGroups();
        }


    }
```

**View.php**

```
           <select class="form-control">
                <?php 
                        $data = $this->delivery_model->getAllGroups();
                foreach($description as $each)
                { ?><option value="<?php echo $each['description']; ?>"><?php echo $each['description']; ?></option>';
                <?php }
                ?>
                </select>
```

But the results appear on top of my page. It's not appearing on the dropdown list. What am I doing wrong in here? Help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `return $data;` in your model? Where you did define the `$data` variable?

Comment: @JamshidHashimi I removed the return $data from my model.

Comment: I post a detailed answer. Check if that solve your problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should not be calling your model from your view. Instead try calling you model and setting `$data['groups']` before you load your views.

Also do not echo the row results in your model unless you want it displayed on your page.

**Controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Delivery_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('delivery_model');

    }
    public function index()
    {

        $data['title']= 'Warehouse - Delivery';
        $data['groups'] = $this->delivery_model->getAllGroups();
        $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/navbar',$data);
        $this->load->view('delivery_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/sidebar',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);

    }


}
```

**Model:**

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getAllGroups()
    {
        /*
        $query = $this->db->get('location');

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            echo $row->description;
        }*/

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT description FROM location');


        return $query->result();

        //echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();
    }
```

**View:**

```
       <select class="form-control">
            <?php 

            foreach($groups as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->description.'">'.$row->description.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: Thank you dude! It works already. By the way, did you just use active record?

Comment: when you pass `$data` to your view each key is an accessible variable in your view. Ex: `$data['groups']` in your controller corresponds to `$groups` in your view.

Answer (score 8):

This is what you should do:

**Model**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function getAllGroups()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT description FROM location');
    return $this->db->query($query)->result();
}
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Delivery_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('delivery_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Warehouse - Delivery';
        $data['groups'] = $this->delivery_model->getAllGroups();
        //I take here a sample view, you can put more view pages here
        $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($groups as $each){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each->description; ?>"><?php echo $each->description; ?></option>';
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Codeigniter already has specialized functions that minimize the amount of html that you have to dump in your code:

Model

```
public function description_pulldown(){
    $this->db->from('location');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result() as $row ){
        //this sets the key to equal the value so that
        //the pulldown array lists the same for each
        $array[$row->description] = $row->description;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
    $data['description_list'] = $this->delivery_model->description_pulldown();
    //load all of your view data
    $this->load->view('delivery_view', $data);
}
```

View

```
echo form_label("Description");
echo form_dropdown('description', $description_list, set_value('description'), $description_list);
```

If you need to have the view pull up the previous data in the dropdown list, you can do a foreach loop to obtain the previous value of the dropdown from the database ie... $description = $item->description; and in the view, change the 'set_value('description')' to simply '$description.'

Answer (score 2):

Never call a model from a view. It is doable but the again you lose the point of using an MVC in the first place.
Call the model from your controller. Get the data and pass the data in to your view.

Use like below.

```
public function index(){
    $data['title']= 'Warehouse - Delivery';
    $data['groups'] = $this->delivery_model->getAllGroups();
    $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/navbar',$data);
    $this->load->view('delivery_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/sidebar',$data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
}
```

In your view, simply loop around the `$groups` variable and `echo` to your dropdown.

```
<select class="form-control">
<?php 
$i = 0;
while($i < count($groups)){
  $val= $groups[$i]['value'];
  $des = $groups[$i]['description'];
  echo "<option value='$i'>$des</option>";
}
</select>
```

And your model's function should be,

```
function getAllGroups(){
   $query = $this->db->get('location');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better I think, in your view use:

On your model get all your data in an array with:

```
public function get_all_description()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('description');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

In controller:

```
$data['description']=$this->model->get_all_description();
```

In view:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($description);$i++)
{
    $description2[$description[$i]['description']]=$marque[$i]['description'];
}

echo form_dropdown('description', $description22, set_value('description'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Codeigniter 4 answer.

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $delModel = new delivery_model();
    $groups=$delModel->getAllGroups();
    $data = [

        'title' => 'Warehouse - Delivery',
        'groups' => $groups,

    ];
        return view('include/header',$data);
        return view('include/navbar',$data);
        return view('delivery_view', $data);
        return view('include/sidebar',$data);
        return view('include/footer',$data);

}
```

Model

```
public function getAllGroups()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $query = $db->query("SELECT description FROM location;");
    return $query->getResultArray();
}
```

View

```
<select>
    <?php
      foreach ($groups as $row) {
      echo '<option value="' . $row["description"] . '">' .$row["description"] . '</option>';
      }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('trip_model');
}

public function index(){
    $data['trips']=$this->trip_model->get_all_trips();
    $this->load->view("trip_view",$data);
}

public function trip_add(){
    if(!empty($_FILES['trip_image']['name'])){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assests/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;
        $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['trip_image']['name'];

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('trip_image')){
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            $trip_image = $uploadData['file_name'];
        }
        else{
            $trip_image = 'Hello..!!';
        }
    }
    else{
        $trip_image = 'Byeee..!!';
    }

    $data = array(
        'trip_image' => $trip_image,
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
        'trip_datetime' => $this->input->post('trip_datetime')
    );

    $insert = $this->trip_model->trip_add($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

function do_upload(){
    $url = "assests/images/";
    $image = basename($_FILES['trip_image']['name']);
    $image = str_replace(' ','|',$image);
    $type = explode(".",$image);
    $type = $type[count($type)-1];

    if (in_array($type,array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'))){
        $tmppath="assests/images/".uniqid(rand()).".".$type;
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["trip_image"]["tmp_name"])){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['trip_image']['tmp_name'],$tmppath);
            return $tmppath;
        }
    }
}
public function ajax_edit($id){
    $data = $this->trip_model->get_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function trip_update(){
    if(!empty($_FILES['trip_image']['name'])){
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assests/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
        $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['trip_image']['name'];

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->upload_img('trip_image')){
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
            $trip_image = $uploadData['file_name'];
        }
        else{
            $trip_image = 'Hello..!!';
        }
    }
    else{
        $trip_image = 'Byeee..!!';
    }

    $data = array(
        'trip_image' => $trip_image,
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'location' => $this->input->post('location'),
        'trip_datetime' => $this->input->post('trip_datetime')
    );

    $this->trip_model->trip_update(array('trip_id' => $this->input->post('trip_id')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}

public function trip_delete($id){
    $this->trip_model->delete_by_id($id);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

}