# Pass the string value of drop down using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I made a web application that have three dropdown list in it. My problem is that when I am now saving to database the id was saved instead of the value in the drop down list. Here is my model code for the drop downs:

```
function get_store()
{
    $this->db->select('ID');
    $this->db->select('StoreName');
    $this->db->from('store');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    // array to store id and storename
    $id = array('-SELECT-');
    $storename = array('-SELECT-');

    for($i = 0;$i < count($result);$i++)
    {
        array_push($id,$result[$i]->ID);
        array_push($storename,$result[$i]->StoreName);
    }
    return $store_result = array_combine($id,$storename);
}

function get_supplier()
{
    $this->db->select('ID');
    $this->db->select('SupplierName');
    $this->db->from('supplier');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    // array to store id and storename
    $id = array('-SELECT-');
    $suppliername = array('-SELECT-');

    for($i = 0;$i < count($result);$i++)
    {
        array_push($id,$result[$i]->ID);
        array_push($suppliername,$result[$i]->SupplierName);
    }
    return $supplier_result = array_combine($id,$suppliername);
}

function get_operation()
{
    $this->db->select('ID');
    $this->db->select('OperationName');
    $this->db->from('operation');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    // array to store id and storename
    $id = array('-SELECT-');
    $operationname = array('-SELECT-');

    for($i = 0;$i < count($result);$i++)
    {
        array_push($id,$result[$i]->ID);
        array_push($operationname,$result[$i]->OperationName);
    }
    return $operation_result = array_combine($id,$operationname);
}
```

and this is the code in my controller that I use:

```
$data['store'] = $this->wip_model->get_store();
    $data['suppliersname'] = $this->wip_model->get_supplier();
    $data['operation'] = $this->wip_model->get_operation();
```

and this is how I used it in my view:

```
<?php $attributes = 'class="form-control" id="store"';
        echo form_dropdown('store',$store,set_value('store',$store),$attributes);?>
```

Kindly help me because I am stuck...

[image]

is this what you need?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Store Name</label>
      <?php $attributes = 'class="form-control" id="store"';
        echo form_dropdown('store',$store,set_value('store',$store),$attributes);?>
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('store');?></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: also share the html that produce by form_dropdown.

Comment: Html of only drop down will also be fine.

Comment: and suppliersname and operation also work fine??? or not?

Comment: I think I found a solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922143/display-data-from-database-to-dropdown-codeigniter and I will try it if this solve also my problem...

Answer (score 0):

see this

```
 <select name="agama" id="agama">
    <option value="1">store 1</option>
    <option value="2">store 2</option>
    </select>
```

in this code,when we posting the values to controller,we get values 1 or 2. 
The same situation in your problem. you can do it in 2 ways.
one is that. when you get the id,you can write a model query to find the name of that id.
otherwise you can set option value as  value in the drop down list

Comment: I am using codeigniter and bootstrap I don't know how will i implement that in the code....

Comment: I experience the problem again, when I saved the input to database,  the Id was saved instead of the description value that i passed to dropdown control.....

Comment: @silverRay,if the id is passed to the database,you can fetch the names corresponding to that id's from database. i am doing like that for all dropdownlist. Do you need example code that i have done? if you need i wil give you

Comment: Yes, can I check if it can answer my problem and also if I am not using codeigniter just plain php I already done it but I need to build the system with framework to make it faster...