# Codeigniter : Auto Fill DropDown From Database not working

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to fetch data in a drop down field from database in Code Igniter. Here is the code for it :

```
<input type="hidden" 
       id="tour_package_id" 
       class="form-control" 
       name="tour_package_id" />
<?php $i='class="form-control" 
          name="tour_name"
          id="tour_name"'; 
          echo form_dropdown('tour_package_id', $tour_list, 
                             set_value('tour_package_id', $tour_package_id),$i);?></div>
```

I am getting the following error for that.

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: tour_package_id
Filename: Packages/add_location.php
Line Number: 40
```

Tried all the stuff but its not working.

Thanks
Bhagya

Comment: you can check this solution for your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922143/display-data-from-database-to-dropdown-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

is a drop down a combobox right?

try this:(this is a hard code just change it)

example:

```
   Table(tbl_Category)
    ID   |  Category_Name
     1       Hardware
     2       Software



   Model
     public function getCategory(){
          $this->db->select('*');
          $this->db->from('tbl_Category');
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query;
     }

   Controller(The trigger to view)(load the model also)
      public function show(){
         $this->data["result"] = $this->Model->getCategory();
         $this->load->view('Category',$this->data); //this->data will get the result value to your view
      }

   The view(Category.php)
   <select>
      <?php foreach($result as $results){ ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $results->ID; ?>"><?php echo $results->Category; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   </select>
```

The foreach inside the select makes it great! like if i add more Category the option will automatically adds up! Try this! hope this helps!