# Getting a drop down list from a database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I have been trying to populate the drop down list on the view page with data from the database with no success. I tried using the recomendations from this question but the drop down is still empty ([display data from database to dropdown CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922143/display-data-from-database-to-dropdown-codeigniter))

Here is my view:

```
<label>City</label>
<select class="form-control>
    <option value="">All</option>
    <?php
    foreach($groups as $city)
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$city['cityidd'].'">'.$city['city'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>  
</select> <br/>
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php 
class Main_controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         $this->load->helper('url'); 
         $this->load->database(); 
    } 

      public function index() 
    { 
         $this->load->helper('form'); 
         $this->load->view('supplier_add'); 
    } 
}
```

Here is my model:

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        /* Call the Model constructor */
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function getAllGroups()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT city FROM citys');

        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

The table name is "citys" then the corresponding column heads are "cityidd" and "city"

Comment: inside the construct() you load module  like this $this->load->model('Site_model');. Then in index function $data['city']=$this->Site_model->getAllGroups();

Comment: is there any error or show output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issue found there. Make changes as below

```
 function __construct(){ 
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load_model('Site_model');
    $this->load->database(); 
} 
public function index(){ 
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $data['groups'] = $this->site_model->getAllGroups();
  $this->load->view('supplier_add',$data); 
}
```

Finally model

```
function getAllGroups(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT cityidd,city FROM citys');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and now test

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm! I My drop down list is now populated. Thanks Rejoanul Alam

Comment: What if I have many drop down lists that I want to populate from the database? Do I add the query for the other drop downs or how do I go about here?  E.g the table is still "citys" then the other corresponding column heads are "id" and "paymentmodes" for another option

Comment: Yes use different query for that with different method like `getAllGroups()`

Answer (score 1):

First change your SELECT query as

```
SELECT cityidd, city FROM citys
```

In the index() of controller change the code as

```
public function index() 
{ 
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $data['groups'] = $this->site_model->getAllGroups();
     $this->load->view('supplier_add',$data); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to call your model method and pass it to view in the controller, code:

```
public function index() 
{ 
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->model('site_model'); 
$data['groups'] = $this->site_model->getAllGroups();
$this->load->view('supplier_add',$data); 
}
```

if you are working on linux dont forget upper and lowercase names!

Answer (score 0):

class Main_controller extends CI_Controller 
            {

```
        function __construct() 
        { 
             parent::__construct(); 
             $this->load->helper('url'); 
             $this->load->database(); 
             $this->load->model('Site_model');
        } 

          public function index() 
        { 
             $this->load->helper('form'); 
             $data['groups']=$this->Site_model->getAllGroups();
             $this->load->view('supplier_add',$data); 
        } 
        }
```

Here is my model:

```
        class Site_model extends CI_Model
        {

        public function __construct() 
        {
            /* Call the Model constructor */
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function getAllGroups()
            {

                $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM citys');


                return $query->result();

            }
        }
```

Try like this

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes

**IN Model** convert data to array as you are using it as array in view so change to this

```
function getAllGroups()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM citys');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function index() 
{ 
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('site_model'); 
    $data['groups'] = $this->site_model->getAllGroups();
    $this->load->view('supplier_add',$data); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading model load the Model
for example:-

```
        function __construct() 
        { 
             parent::__construct(); 
             $this->load->helper('url');
             $this->load->model('Site_model') 
             $this->load->database(); 
        } 

          public function index() 
        { 
             $this->load->helper('form');
             $data['record']=$this->Site_model->getAllGroups()
             $this->load->view('supplier_add', $data); 
        } 
        }
```

Model:-
class Site_model extends CI_Model
            {

```
        public function __construct() 
        {
            /* Call the Model constructor */
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function getAllGroups()
            {

                $query = $this->db->query('SELECT city FROM citys');


                return $query->result();

            }
        }
```