# displaying data from database using select options codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

my `controller` function

```
public function add_books() {

  $this->load->model('User');

  $data['books'] = $this->User->getAuthor();

  $this->load->view('vadd_books',$data);

}
```

my `user_model` model

```
function getAuthor() {

  $this->db->select('author_firstname, author_lastname');

  $this->db->from('authors');

  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: if your result is more than one you need to use foreach loop and display it in the html table.

Comment: I already used foreach in my view. Should I post my view here?

Comment: yes can you post it?

Comment: could you please check did you got proper data from your model?

Comment: I got a proper data from my model. My problem is just displaying/using my foreach.

Comment: can you post your view ?

Answer (score 0):

### Change in controller [Modelname](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/models.html)

```
public function add_books() {

  $this->load->model('user_model');

  $data['books'] = $this->user_model->getAuthor();

  $this->load->view('vadd_books',$data);

}
```

Use `$this->db->last_query()` to print query in model to [debug MySQL Query](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html)

Comment: But @RobertCapistrano Which answer is correct if any then please mark correct as correct answer ...:)

Comment: yes @RobertCapistrano which answer works for you please mark that as correct answer that will also help to other :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code

```
<select class="form-control">
            <?php 

            foreach($books as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->author_firstname.'">'.$row->author_firstname.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
```

For more reference refer url : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922143/display-data-from-database-to-dropdown-codeigniter`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one code. i try to explain step by step.

**Model**

```
public function getAuthor() {

   $this->db->select('author_firstname, author_lastname');
   $this->db->from('authors');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function add_books() {

  $this->load->model('User');
  $data['books'] = $this->User->getAuthor();
  $this->load->view('vadd_books',$data);
}
```

**View**

```
  <select class="form-control my-class">
        <?php 

        foreach($books as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->author_firstname.'">'.$row->author_firstname.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
```