# how to get data in dropdown from database in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi any one help me how to get data in drop down from database in codeigniter.below is my code it is not work working. The below code is not working properly the drop down not appearing when click please help me to get data. I am doing it in codeigniter. I want to get data from database in dropdown. I think the code is perfect am new to codeigniter  the below code is not working properly the drop down not appearing when click please help me to get data. I am doing it in codeigniter. I want to get data from database in dropdown. I think the code is perfect am new to codeigniter

**Model:**

```
public function getdepartment() {
     $query = $this->db->query("select department from object_data");
     $result = $this->executeSelectQuery($query);
     return $result;
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h4> Courses:</h4>
    <?php $dp = $this->base_model->getdepartment(); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
      <select name="report_type" class="form-control">
      <?php foreach($dp as $row) { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row->department.'">'.$row->department.'</option>';
      }?>
      </select>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function employe() {
     $data['title'] = 'title'; 
     $this->load->model('base_model');
     $data['groups'] = $this->base_model->getCourseAll();
     $data['dprtmnt'] = $this->base_model->getdepartment();
     $this->load->view('employe', $data);
}
```

the above code is not working properly the drop down not appearing when click please help me to get data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display data from database to dropdown CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922143/display-data-from-database-to-dropdown-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model

```
 public function getdepartment() {
 $query = $this->db->query("select department from object_data");
 return $query->result();
 }
```

controller

```
 public function employe() {
 $data['title'] = 'title'; 
 $this->load->model('base_model');
 $data['groups'] = $this->base_model->getCourseAll();
 $data['dprtmnt'] = $this->base_model->getdepartment();
 $this->load->view('employe', $data);
 }
```

views

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<h4> Courses:</h4>
<?php $dp = $this->base_model->getdepartment(); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <select name="report_type" class="form-control">
  <?php foreach($dprtmnt as $row) { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row->department.'">'.$row-
 >department.'</option>';
  }?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try codeigniter own methods it is the good way for practice.

> Model :

```
public function getdepartment() {
     $query = $this->db->select('department')->from('object_data')->get();
     return $query->result();
 }
```

> Controller :

```
public function employe() {
     $data['title'] = 'title'; 
     $this->load->model('base_model');
     $data['groups'] = $this->base_model->getCourseAll();
     $data['dprtmnt'] = $this->base_model->getdepartment();
     $this->load->view('employe', $data);
 }
```

> Views :

```
<select name="report_type" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($dprtmnt as $row) { 
      echo '<option value="'.$row->department.'">'.$row-
>department.'</option>';
    }?>
</select>
```